# Outlook Web Addin -Office JS - Mutliple 'DialogMessageReceived' event are triggered

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

In my addin, I have a dialog window which opens from the taskpane.On performing an action from the dialog, I'm triggering a 'Office.context.ui.messageParent' event. But the 'DialogMessageReceived' event is being called multiple times. It is working fine on the outlook desktop application. It's only triggered multiple times in Chrome/Safari. Any Suggestions?

```
dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function processMessage(arg){
                    if (arg.type !== Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived) {
                        // TODO: Handle unknown message.
                        return;
                    }
                    if(arg.message){
                        const message = JSON.parse(arg.message);
                        const item= Office.context.mailbox.item;
                        let type='html';
                        let messageFromDialog=message.richText;
                        item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(messageFromDialog, { coercionType:type },function (asyncResult) {
                            if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
                                console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
                            }
                            else {
                                event.completed();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

In the above code,setSelectedDataAsync is being called multiple times.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the stripped down version of your Add-in? Or can you share the code which is triggering Office.context.ui.messageParent event?

Comment: $scope.appendData=function(data){
            const jsonMessage = JSON.stringify({'data':data.text,'richText':data.richText});
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(jsonMessage);
        }

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I've called the above function on button click event. I was able to debug and check that function was being called just once but the DialogMessageReceived event is being triggered multiple times. I'm not sure why that's happening. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: We are not able to repro this issue on our side. You can check for following things in your code
1. messageParent is called exactly once. I believe that you have confirmed this in your previous comment.
2. EventHandler is getting registered exactly once.
 If you can provide a stripped down version of your add-in, we can try to repro this from our side.

Comment: Also, Please let us know if the dialog is being opened as an iframe or not?